# How can use setTimeout() to start a Flash animation?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am desperately trying to get this flash animation to play after 5 seconds, but nothing I do seems to make it work.

This is the code I am using:

```
function waitFiveSec() {
    window.setTimeout(startPlaying,5000);
}

function startPlaying() {
    window.document.getElementById("FlashID")
}
```

I am then calling the waitFiveSec() function on the HTML document:

```
<body onload="waitFiveSec()">
```

This is for a class project where I have to do timeline based events, so I have never really used JavaScript before.

Can anyone help me on this?

HTML Flash Code:

```
<div id="animation">
  <p>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="365" height="295" id="FlashID" title="Tractor Animation">
      <param name="movie" value="../Multimedia elements/Animations/Tractor Animation Opt 2.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
      <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
      <param name="PLAY" value="false" />
      <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../Multimedia elements/Animations/Tractor Animation Opt 2.swf" width="365" height="295">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
        <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
        <param name="PLAY" value="false" />
        <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
        <div>
          <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
          <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
      </object>
      <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `window.document` is not valid. It's `document` only. Use the console to debug your code, and you'll see an error.

Comment: Why would just getting a reference to it using `getElementById()` make it start playing..

Comment: @elclanrs Of course is `window.document` valid. `document` has been a property of `window` since day 1. In fact *every* global variable is a property of `window` in JavaScript.

Comment: Katie, please include the HTML code of the flash object in your page.

Comment: @Tomalak: lol. my bad. I'm so used to see `document` only that I forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong.

Only makee sure the file get loaded before you called from your html.